# How to show "Create site" option on SharePoint home page to only selected users

Tags: sharepoint-online

At present we have below setting in admin center for site creation, which enables create site command to all users.

[image]

Now we want to show the site creation command only to certain users(These users are not SharePoint admins).

Is there any option to do this?

I have already checked this answer, but does not got the answer in the linked articles. [Disabling "Create Site" in SharePoint Online except admins](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226643/disabling-create-site-in-sharepoint-online-except-admins)

Answer (score 1):

The [linked article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226643/disabling-create-site-in-sharepoint-online-except-admins) is for Subsite Creation. User who has not "Create Subsites" permission cannot create subsites and the Create subsite command is hidden for him.

Currently, there is no way to only show the Create site command to specific users.

[Manage site creation in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-creation)

[Allow or prevent users from creating sites and subsites in SharePoint Online](https://tutorials4sharepoint.wordpress.com/2018/11/12/allow-or-prevent-users-from-creating-sites-and-subsites-in-sharepoint-online/)